# PHP - HTTP tunnel for SSH to a remote server

Tags: php, ssh, tunnel, http-tunneling

I have the following problem/idea:

I want to access a hidden remote machine with SSH, but the network I am in does not allow a connection through port 22 (SSH) so I want to try a HTTP or more like a HTTPS tunnel over port 443 to my SSH port 22. But I am a bit limited and so I thought about a 2 server solution where I connect to the first server over the HTTP tunnel and then just forward all SSH requests to the second hidden server.

But I have only PHP on the first server.

The connection should look something like that:

```
 _______        _______       _______
|My     |______|       |_____|Hidden |
|Machine|_HTTP_|Server |_SSH_|Server |
|_______|      |_______|     |_______|
```

(I know the ASCII drawing is not the best)

My Question is now: Can I make a PHP HTTP tunnel with my server to my hidden server? And if yes how? Because the ssh2_tunnel documentation is not good.

Or is there even a easier method to connect to my hidden server?

Comment: How are you planning to utilize the SSH tunnel? Not sure how you're going to leverage HTTP in this scenario. Are you expecting to be able to use an SSH client?

Comment: I am also not that sure but I think something of a HTTP wrapper

Comment: Maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190490/how-to-use-ssh-over-http-or-https will help

Comment: The first server has a domain and subdomains. I would make a subdomain for the tunnel. If I access now the subdomain it will create the tunnel. At least that is my idea

Comment: I looked into the unix stackexchange and only sslh could be a solution but also not the best

Comment: You should use Docker to `expose` the service to the local IPV4 network.

Comment: Where should i use docker? On my machine, on the server or the hidden server?

Comment: Maybe this will help [https://phpseclib.com/docs/connect](https://phpseclib.com/docs/connect)

Comment: It uses a nice lib but only sends one command over the line,  but i need to open a whole session over the tunnel. Maybe you @Alex have an idea if there is a solution for my problem?